# Generating OpenAPI spec for Google Config Connector

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, openapi, gcp-config-connector

I'm trying to use the Kube OpenAPI tool openapi-gen to generate OpenAPI specs for Google's Config Connector.

I'm relatively new to Go, so I'm not sure whether this is a configuration error on my part or if I'm simply using it wrong.

I've cloned the [Kube OpenAPI repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-openapi), and inside of that directory I've cloned the [Config Connector repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector), for simplicity.

This is what's happening when I try to generate an OpenAPI spec file.

```
$ go run cmd/openapi-gen/openapi-gen.go -i ./k8s-config-connector/pkg/apis/serviceusage/v1beta1 -p foo.com/foo -h ./boilerplate/boilerplate.go.txt
E0811 16:45:57.516697   22683 openapi.go:309] Error when generating: TypeMeta, TypeMeta invalid type
2021/08/11 16:45:57 OpenAPI code generation error: Failed executing generator: some packages had errors:
failed to generate default in ./k8s-config-connector/pkg/apis/serviceusage/v1beta1.Service: TypeMeta: not sure how to enforce default for Unsupported
exit status 1
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some troubleshooting steps:

1 - GOROOT variable should be set and point to root of go installation

2-  Operator-sdk depended on it being exported as an environment variable. Run the below command

```
export GOROOT=$(go env GOROOT)
```

when using the operator-sdk, it is necessary to either (a) set GOROOT in your environment, or (b) use the same GOROOT that was used to build the operator-sdk binary.

Refer to the [link](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/issues/2288) for additional information.